# 'Ok Google' auto launch "randomly"

Tags: auto-start, motorola-moto-g3, ok-google

My phone is a Motorola Moto G3. Sometimes, when I'm not using it, 'Ok Google' feature auto launchs and records my voice. I think it could be a bug. Is any workaround to prevent that and not disable the 'Ok Google' voice detection?

Or it's the NSA?

Comment: Try disabling the "OK Google detection" feature in the app settings > voice

Comment: @esQmo I didn't want to disable the "OK Google" detection. There should be another way to prevent that.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue on Samsung J5, disabling the feature solved the problem.

Comment: @esQmo No, because if I do that I will disable that feature, and I want to use it.

Comment: This happens only when the headphones are plugged in? or even when they are not.

Comment: @esQmo This never happens when the headphones are plugged in. Just sometimes, when the phone is locked.

Comment: Seems definitely  like a bug.

Comment: it happens for me sometime even in between calls.